# Calling a function directly vs calling a function from a class in android studios?

Tags: java, android

I am working on two Android studio project. 
In both the projects I have called the function **get_LTE_Rsrp()**:

```
int get_LTE_Rsrp() {
      try {
            Method[] methods = android.telephony.SignalStrength.class.getMethods();

                    for (Method mthd : methods) {
                        if (mthd.getName().equals(LTE_RSRP_STRENGTH)) {   //(TAG)LTE_RSRP_STRENGTH ="getLteRsrp" which is a method inside the SignalStrength.java class
                            int LteRsrpStrength = (Integer) mthd.invoke(signalStrength, new Object[]{});
                            return LteRsrpStrength;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LTE_TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
                }
                return 1;   //some default value
            }
```

**In the first project it is called in the following manner**

```
onCreate {

    // some code

    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    final PhoneStateListener mListener = new PhoneStateListener() {

        @Override

        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength sStrength) {

            signalStrength = sStrength;

            mRSRP = get_LTE_Rsrp();

            //display mRSRP in a textview

        }
    }
}
```

**Now, in the second project i have created a class named CellularSignalInfo and made get_LTE_Rsrp() as one of its methods.**

implementation of CellularSignalInfo

```
    class CellularSignalInfo {

        final static String LTE_RSRP_STRENGTH = "getLteRsrp";

        SignalStrength signalStrength;
        int cRSRP;

        public int get_LTE_Rsrp() {
            try {

                Log.d("TAG1", "inside LTE RSRP");
                Method[] methods = android.telephony.SignalStrength.class.getMethods();

                for (Method mthd : methods) {
                    Log.d("TAG2", "inside for");
                    if (mthd.getName().equals(LTE_RSRP_STRENGTH)) {
                        Log.d("TAG3", "inside if");
                        int LteRsrpStrength = (Integer) mthd.invoke(signalStrength, new Object[]{});
                        return LteRsrpStrength;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LTE_TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
                Log.d("TAG4", "inside catch");

            }

            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Now,

**int LteRsrpStrength = (Integer) mthd.invoke(signalStrength, new Object[]{});
                            return LteRsrpStrength;**

this particular line of code works in the first project(and a corresponding value  say -111 dBm is returned) 
but in the second case only the default value is returned. I have tried adding logs inside the for, if, catch, which shows the code do get executed upto that point, but the particular line of code is not executed.

What could be the reason behind this problem ?

Comment: How did you pass `signalStrength` to `CellularSignalInfo` in your second approach? Add detail implementation of `CellularSignalInfo`

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection in order to invoke a method in class `SignalStrength` ?

Comment: @shubham, Edit your post and add `CellularSignalInfo`

Comment: Since the value needs to be updated everytime there is change in signal strength , hence reflection is used to invoke the the method at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you didn't initialize `signalStrength` inside `CellularSignalInfo`. Change your `CellularSignalInfo` like below:

```
class CellularSignalInfo {

    SignalStrength signalStrength;
    int cRSRP;
    final static String LTE_RSRP_STRENGTH = "getLteRsrp";

    public CellularSignalInfo(SignalStrength sStrength) {
        signalStrength = sStrength;
    }

    public int get_LTE_Rsrp() {
        try {

            Log.d("TAG1", "inside LTE RSRP");
            Method[] methods = android.telephony.SignalStrength.class.getMethods();

            for (Method mthd : methods) {
                Log.d("TAG2", "inside for");
                if (mthd.getName().equals(LTE_RSRP_STRENGTH)) {
                    Log.d("TAG3", "inside if");
                    int LteRsrpStrength = (Integer) mthd.invoke(signalStrength, new Object[]{});
                    return LteRsrpStrength;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LTE_TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
            Log.d("TAG4", "inside catch");

        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And call like below:

```
CellularSignalInfo cellularSignalInfo = new CellularSignalInfo(sStrength);
mRSRP = cellularSignalInfo.get_LTE_Rsrp();
```

Comment: @Shubham, Have you tried this?  Is this solve your problem?